# Word Transformations

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, poetry

> I am a gap
>
> Rearranged, an accelerator
>
> Take one and rearrange, an animal
>
> Rearrange that, a skin condition.
>
> ---
>
> I am a gap
>
> Take one and rearrange, a garden tool
>
> Take one again and rearrange, a boat.
>
> ---
>
> I am a gap
>
> Take one and I'm a type of mouth.
>
> ---
>
> I am a gap.

*Please give the word described by each line. The "gap" word is the same word each time; there is no need for you to type it four times.*

Comment: @Randal'Thor I'm on the fence with the riddle tag. (Also glad you like the puzzle :D)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word is

> Break

**Reasons**

I am a gap

Rearranged, an accelerator

> Brake (negative accelerator per OP)

Take one and rearrange, an animal

> Bear

Rearrange that, a skin condition.

> Bare

I am a gap

Take one and rearrange, a garden tool

> Rake

Take one again and rearrange, a boat.

> Ark

I am a gap

Take one and I'm a type of mouth.

> Beak

I am a gap.

Comment: But that's the opposite of accelerator ... ?

Comment: @Randal'Thor technically no. It just produces negative acceleration.

Comment: @Randal'Thor: Good point, but everything else makes sense, so I'm just throwing this out there.

Comment: Tricksy, tricksy @Brandon :-) I like the unexpected parts of this.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Checkmark will be awarded once this gets a few more views.